# implementing three type of users - Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I'm building an application and I'm new to Laravel.

In this application, there are 3 kinds of users that interact with it: user1, user2,user3

user3 must related to one of user2

is it possible to do like :

user : id , name , is_related_to_another , user_id

for user1 : 1 , Ali , 0 , Null

for user2 : 2 , AA  , 0 , Null

for user3 : 3 , AAA , 1 , 2

is it correct ? any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Instead of explicitly saying `is_related_to_another`, you can assume the relationship state based on whether a `user_id` is set.

Make sure to look at the Eloquent relationship documentation from Laravel, you will get an in depth explanation of how to make this work.